# Can we make a multipart request without using enctype attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying to write a `multipart file upload`, and for this, i already have a form and a file upload button inside it.

Now, for this, i need to place `enctype` attribute with in `form` tag, now the problem is i don't want to send the whole form elements with this `multipart` request!

I want to do this `file upload` before form submission and then fill all the input elements in the form and then submit, and I cannot insert another `form` tag in the existing parent `form` tag.

Is there any alternate approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Upload file using ajax onblur event of the file field, and then do the regular form submission.

Comment: Which is fine, but what will be the value of `content-type` in ajax request? will it be `false` or `multipart`?

Comment: Not too sure.. But this might help - https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Will check. And you can answer instead of commenting! :)